# Map keys to emit function

Tags: javascript, object, mapreduce, couchdb, nosql

i've got an object in couchDB and in this looks like are several arrays, im new to couchDB and i don't know how to access the keys of it. The document looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "113232",
   "_rev": "1-c967a81c0eccba6a7c92e3c4b352d4eb",
   "name": "Ezequiel Campion",
   "vorlesungen": [
       {
           "Ethik": 1.7
       },
       {
           "Glaube und Wissen": 5
       },
       {
           "Logik": 1.7
       },
       {
           "Bioethik": 1.7
       },
       {
           "Erkenntnistheorie": 1
       },
       {
           "Grundzuege": 4
       },
       {
           "Der Wiener Kreis": 1.7
       }
   ]
}
```

I just want to have the keys like Ethik, Glaube und Wissen,... not the values to this keys. 
My actual map functions looks like this:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.vorlesungen, null);
  }
```

the output is for example:

```
[{"Bioethik": 1}]
```

now i only want the value Bioethik, could anyone tell me how to access it? i've already tried .keys() like usual with JS Arrays and i've also tried to perform a JSON.encode before using keys() but there is no output in this case. I think that it will be just a trivial answer because i don't know the syntax...

regards
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after long testing i've found a solution for my problem:

```
function(doc) {
  var vorl;
  if(doc.vorlesungen){
    for(i=0;i<doc.vorlesungen.length;i++){
      for(vorl in doc.vorlesungen[i]){
        emit(vorl, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this shows me the corret output, but i think it's not very pretty cause of the for loops. In college cases like this were solved with foreach loops to iterate the array, but i don't get 'em working. Could anybody show me an example foreach to this case please?

Comment: isn't it the same as the solution of @Akshat Jiwan Sharma presented before? just with traditional - non-functional - array iteration

Comment: i've tried the version of @Akshat Jiwan Sharma but it doesn't gave me an output, i've no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 function(doc){
    doc.vorlesungen.forEach(function(item){
        if(typeof(item) === "object"){
          var keys = Object.keys(item);
         keys.forEach(function(key){emit(key)})
        }
    });
}
```

The code iterates over the array `doc.vorlesungen`. If the item is an object it gets all the keys of the object. Then for each key so obtained it emits it.

This is the result I get when running the view

```
{"total_rows":7,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"113232","key":"Bioethik","value":null},
{"id":"113232","key":"Der Wiener Kreis","value":null},
{"id":"113232","key":"Erkenntnistheorie","value":null},
{"id":"113232","key":"Ethik","value":null},
{"id":"113232","key":"Glaube und Wissen","value":null},
{"id":"113232","key":"Grundzuege","value":null},
{"id":"113232","key":"Logik","value":null}
]}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this code doesn't give me any output, i'm executing it on futon webinterface for couchdb (v1.3.0). Is there any way to troubleshoot the script in this interface?

Comment: There is a [log()](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/query-server/javascript.html?highlight=log#log) function that can help you a bit in debugging.